# How to convert scientific notation to decimal in tibbles?

Tags: r, tibble

Although basic, I can't find an answer anywhere: how can I disable scientific notation in tibbles, and have the tibble display decimals instead?

### My data

I have a simple tibble, resulted from `lm() %>% broom::tidy()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

## I used dput() to get this:

tidy_lm_output <- structure(list(term = c("(Intercept)", "mood", "sleep"), estimate = c(-0.00000000000000028697849703988, 
-0.0746522106739049, 0.835867664974019), std.error = c(0.0319620048196539, 
0.0464197056030362, 0.0464197056030362), statistic = c(-0.00000000000000897873893265334, 
-1.60820086435494, 18.006742053085), p.value = c(0.999999999999993, 
0.108628280589954, 9.41480010964234e-53)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> tidy_lm_output
## # A tibble: 3 x 5
##  term         estimate std.error statistic   p.value
##   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 (Intercept) -2.87e-16    0.0320 -8.98e-15 10.00e- 1
## 2 mood        -7.47e- 2    0.0464 -1.61e+ 0  1.09e- 1
## 3 sleep        8.36e- 1    0.0464  1.80e+ 1  9.41e-53
```

Strangely enough, only the "std.error" column displays in decimals, but all the other columns are in scientific notation.

**I'd like to get all columns to show information in decimals, while still as a tibble.**

### Attempts to solve this

- The go-to solution of `options(scipen=999)` did not work.
- Using `format(scientific = FALSE)` didn't work either.

### This questions asked elsewhere

- Was asked [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-a-tibble/24444) by somebody but remained unanswered.

Comment: Do you _really_ want 53 zeros in your p-value column? I don't think you do

Comment: Not 53 zeros, but I'll be happy with some rounding too. If the number means practically 0, then be it. I just want an interpretable display.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can control the number of significant digits printed by using `options(pillar.sigfig = 5)`.

```
tidy_lm_output
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term           estimate std.error   statistic    p.value
  <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 (Intercept) -2.8698e-16  0.031962 -8.9787e-15 1.0000e+ 0
2 mood        -7.4652e- 2  0.046420 -1.6082e+ 0 1.0863e- 1
3 sleep        8.3587e- 1  0.046420  1.8007e+ 1 9.4148e-53
```

For more info on how to format tibbles see `help(format.tbl)`

However, if you just want to round these figures you can do:

```
tidy_lm_output %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 5)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)   0         0.0320      0      1    
2 mood         -0.0746    0.0464     -1.61   0.109
3 sleep         0.836     0.0464     18.0    0
```

Comment: It's the second part of your answer that I was looking for.

Comment: In case `mutate_if` becomes deprecated (it's now marked as superseded), the new preferred syntax for the `mutate_if` line is `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 5))`

Answer (score 3):

`format` is a *base* function that does not support tibbles. So to use it, convert your tibble to a data frame first:

#### Tidyverse Pipe Style

https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html

```
my_formatted_df <- my_tibble %>% as.data.frame() %>% format(scientific=FALSE)
```

#### Nested Function Style

```
my_formatted_df <- format(as.data.frame(my_tibble), scientific = FALSE)
```